# JVM crashing in Solaris box Problematic frame: # C [libc.so.1]# [ timer expired, abort... ]

Tags: java, crash, jvm, solaris

JVM(JDK 1.7) crashing in Solaris(5.11) box  with following error.

> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>       #
>       #  SIGBUS (0xa) at pc=0xffffffff7eb83be0, pid=11981, tid=3599
>       #
>       # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
>       # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode solaris-sparc compressed oops)
>       # Problematic frame:
>       # C  [libc.so.1+0x83be0]# [ timer expired, abort... ]
>
> ```
> $ pkg info entire
>           Name: entire
>        Summary: Incorporation to lock all system packages to the same build
>    Description: This package constrains system package versions to the same
>                 build.  WARNING: Proper system update and correct package
>                 selection depend on the presence of this incorporation.
>                 Removing this package will result in an unsupported system.
>       Category: Meta Packages/Incorporations
>          State: Installed
>      Publisher: solaris
>        Version: 0.5.11
>  Build Release: 5.11
>         Branch: 0.175.1.0.0.24.2
> Packaging Date: September 19, 2012 07:01:35 PM
>           Size: 5.46 kB
>           FMRI: pkg://solaris/entire@0.5.11,5.11-0.175.1.0.0.24.2:20120919T190135Z
> ```

```
java -version
```

> ```
> java version "1.7.0_67"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Once we migrated to JDK 8 JVM crash is not happening