# Websphere 8.5 crashes on accessing application

Tags: crash, websphere

I have a EAR which after deploying into WAS 8.5 looks fine. But after accessing for few minutes, the server restarts automatically. The exception captured captured in native_stdout shows the log as below:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0xa) at pc=0x001ffffeff3e6ea0, pid=15451, tid=239
#
# JRE version: 7.0_17-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode solaris-sparc compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.1+0xe6ea0]# [ timer expired, abort... ]
[7/13/17 18:32:28:111 SGT] 00000001 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0018I: The trace state has changed. The new trace state is *=info.
[7/13/17 18:32:28:520 SGT] 00000001 ManagerAdmin  A   TRAS0007I: Logging to the service log is disabled
[7/13/17 18:32:28:731 SGT] 00000001 ProviderTrack I com.ibm.ffdc.osgi.ProviderTracker AddingService FFDC1007I: FFDC Provider Installed:
```

The same application works fine in other environment. Thanks in advance for any help on identifying the problem.

Comment: You are using Oracle java7 on Solaris to run this WAS instead of IBM one? On other envs also? There should be FFDC log created that might provide more details.

Comment: And it looks more than JVM problem that WebSphere. Comapre java versions on other servers and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714352/jvm-crashing-in-solaris-box-problematic-frame-c-libc-so-1-timer-expired